# How to render a page with form fields and validate these fields on another page

Tags: html, forms, post, razor, webmatrix

I have a page **ProjectField.cshtml** which contains all the fields in a project.
In the HTML page I have is this:

```
@{
    WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

    // Initialize general page variables
    var name = Request.Form["name"];
    var description = Request.Form["description"];
    int groupId;
    if (Request.Form["groupId"] != null)
    {
        groupId = Request.Form["groupId"].AsInt();
    }
    else
    {
        groupId = -1;
    }

    var menutitle = Request.Form["menutitle"];
}
<div>
    <div class="row-project">
        @Html.Label("Grupo: ", "group")
    </div>
    <select id="group" name="group">
        <option value="-1" @{ if(groupId < 0) { <text>selected="true"</text> } } label="--Selecione--">--Selecione--</option>
        <option value="0" @{ if(groupId == 0) { <text>selected="true"</text> } } label="Residencial">Residencial</option>
        <option value="1" @{ if(groupId == 1) { <text>selected="true"</text> } } label="Comercial">Comercial</option>
        <option value="2" @{ if(groupId == 2) { <text>selected="true"</text> } } label="Institucional">Institucional</option>
        <option value="3" @{ if(groupId == 3) { <text>selected="true"</text> } } label="Mostras">Mostras</option>
    </select>
    @Html.ValidationMessage("group")
</div>

<div>
    <div class="row-project">
        @Html.Label("Projeto: ", "project")
    </div>
    @Html.TextBox("project", name)
    @Html.ValidationMessage("project")
</div>

<div>
    <div class="row-project">
        @Html.Label("Título Menu: ", "menutitle")
    </div>
    @Html.TextBox("menutitle", menutitle)
    @Html.ValidationMessage("menutitle")
</div>

<div>
    <div class="row-project">
        @Html.Label("Descrição: ", "description")
    </div>
    @Html.TextArea("description", description, 4, 35, null)
    @Html.ValidationMessage("description")
</div>


<div class="upload">
    <div>
    @Html.Label("Imagens: ", "images")
    </div>
    @FileUpload.GetHtml(
        initialNumberOfFiles:1,
        allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:true,
        includeFormTag:true,
        addText:"Adicionar",
        uploadText:"Salvar")
    @Html.ValidationMessage("images")
</div>
<div class="row center-button clear">
    <!--<input type="submit" name="action" value="Salvar" title="Salvar"/>-->
</div>
```

In my page **Create.cshtml** I ride the html using the method RederPage to render page **ProjectFields.cshtml** .
See the complete code:

```
@{
        WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

        Layout = "~/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
        Page.Title = "Novo Projeto";

        // Initialize general page variables
        var name = Request.Form["name"];
        var description = Request.Form["description"];
        int groupId = Request.Form["groupId"].AsInt();
        var menutitle = Request.Form["menutitle"];

        if (IsPost) 
        {   
            // Validate
            if (name.IsEmpty()) 
            {
                ModelState.AddError("project", "Nome do projeto é obrigatório.");
            }

            if (menutitle.IsEmpty()) 
            {
                ModelState.AddError("menutitle", "Título do menu é obrigatório.");
            }

            if (groupId < 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddError("group", "Grupo é obrigatório.");
            }

            if (Request.Files.Count <= 0 || Request.Files[0].ContentLength <= 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddError("images", "Insira pelo menos uma imagem.");
            }

            // Confirm there are no validation errors
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                 //CODE FOR SAVE DATA...
            }
        }

}

@if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary("Houve um problema no cadastro de projeto", true, new{ @class="error" })
}
<form id="contact" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@Href(@"~\Project\Create")">
    <fieldset>
        @RenderPage(Href("~/Project/Views/ProjectField.cshtml"))
    </fieldset>
</form>

@BindHelpers.Link(Href("~/Project/Index"), "Lista de projetos", "projects", "projects-link")
```

But when I make the post, it does not validate the data.
I noticed that it runs the post form **Create.cshtml** and then immediately post the **ProjectField.cshtml** but that will validate the fields is the same **Create.cshtml**.

Comment: don't forget the title too :) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry again, I corrected the problem.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will help you but, I don't see a form tag (or the helper to make one, if indeed there is such a helper). Am I missing something? I do see your input type "submit" tag, but I couldn't see a form tag (with action set to Create.cshtml).

Hope this helps!